# Unity 3d script adding functions as trigger on Inspector window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have defined three functions (OnReticleEnter(),Exit() and hover()) in the script and attached with a game object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using TMPro;
public class MyObject : MonoBehaviour
{
        // Custom reticle events
    public GameObject gOBJ;
    void OnReticleEnter()
    {
        gOBJ.SetActive(true);
    }
    void OnReticleExit()
    {
        gOBJ.SetActive(false);
    }
    void OnReticleHover()
    {
        gOBJ.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

My problem is I want these functions in the inspector window so that I can define multiple actions like event trigger's pointer enter.
Is there any way I can make these functions available as event trigger on inspector window?

Comment: You'd have to write your own Editor Script to expose these functions in the editor. You can override `OnInspectorGUI` and implement your code. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.OnInspectorGUI.html

Comment: Many thanks for swift reply. When I add the script and change OnInspectorGUI to OnReticleEnter, I get error: no suitable method found to override"

Comment: You cant change OnInspectorGUI to your function. You have to write code INSIDE on OnInspectorGUI to draw whatever you need. Take a look at some examples and it'll make sense

Comment: Yes. I followed example and tried in same way. The error seems to continue. My function seems not available for some reason. Or could you suggest if there is any easy way to convert my function OnReticleEnter() to PointerEnter? So that I can use default event trigger?

Comment: Make your function public? public void OnReticleHover(){}......?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now I made the functions public...but still it is in accessible under OninspectorGUI